# Java 15 - records with different return type for getter

Tags: java, java-record, java-15

Is it possible to implement something like this in java 15?

```
record Something(
        SomeId id,
        MyProp myProp,
        MaybeProp maybeProp
){
    public Something(SomeId id, MyProp myProp){
        this(id, myProp, null);
    }

    public Optional<MaybeProp> maybeProp(){ //problematic line
        return Optional.ofNullable(maybeProp);
    }
}
```

Here I get the exception

`(return type of accessor method maybeProp() must match the type of record component maybeProp)`

So - I understand what the problem is; But is there then some other solution for this? How to have optional member inside record, that I do not need to initialize using `Optional.of()`?

Comment: Just to clarify - you want the record field to be a reference, with `null` meaning 'not present' but you want it returned as an `Optional` when the user asks for the value? If that's your question then the answer is that it's not possible to hide or change the return type of the automatically generated read accessor for each field. You would need to have an additional accessor with a different name that returns the `Optional` using `ofNullable`

Comment: exactly. That will work, just a bit ugly. I guess I would also have to somehow disable that `maybeProp` so it doesn't get called.

Comment: I'll add a different suggestion as an answer

Comment: What about changing the type of maybeProp to Optional<MaybeProp> and doing the wrapping in the constructor instead of the getter?

Comment: @tgdavies is that possible in that autogenerated constructor?

Comment: @tgdavies I think that's what OP means by 'initialize using Optionla.of'

Comment: @BojanVukasovic You'd need to write you own constructor, and the autogenerated constructor which takes an Optional<> would still exist.

Comment: The essential tradeoff of records is: you have given up the ability to decouple your API from your representation; the API for construction and access is derived directly from the state description.  So, no.  If the type of a component is `T`, then the type of its corresponding accessor and canonical constructor parameter will also be `T`.  (But you can have additional constructors.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't hide or change the return type of the automatically generated read accessor for a record's field.

One way to achieve what you are looking for is to have the record implement an interface and then use that instead of the record type:

```
interface PossibleSomething {
    Optional<Something> maybeSomething();
}

record SomethingRecord(Something something) implements PossibleSomething {
    public Optional<Something> maybeSomething() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(something);
    }
}

// user code:
PossibleSomething mySomething = new SomethingRecord(something);
mySomething.maybeSomething().ifPresent(...)
```

By using `PossibleSomething` in the calling code you are explicitly declaring that you don't need direct access to the field but will access it only through the interface's accessor.

As a matter of design philosophy, records are explicitly intended (according to the [JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359)) to support *modelling data as data*. In other words their use case is when you have straight immutable data you want to store and give the user direct access to. That is why they don't support changing the accessors: it's not what records are for. The pattern I show above (i.e. a record implementing an interface to hide access) is a way to hide the use of a record as an implementation detail and control access to the fields.

Comment: thanks. I can always use the class. Just wanted to know if record is an option.

Comment: and the other problem that the OP has posted, of trying to hide the actual accessor would still exist with this pattern.

Comment: @Naman not sure what you mean by that. Because the reference is assigned to a variable with the interface's type there's no method for accessing the data.

Comment: @sprinter I guess he is saying that if you use it like `SomethingRecord mySomething` (which you could), you will still have that `mySomething.something()` accessor.

Comment: @BojanVukasovic as mentioned in the first sentence of my answer, it's not possible to hide the public accessor of a record.

Comment: @sprinter yes, I just commented what he meant :)